# Gershgorin Circle Theorem in Infinite Dimensional Vector Spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request

Do there exist any generalizations of the [Gershgorin Circle Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gershgorin_circle_theorem) to infinite dimensional vector spaces?

Comment: What specific sources are you familiar with? Do you have any reason to believe this theorem can be extended infinite dimensional vector spaces?

Comment: I've seen this theorem discussed in _Matrix Analysis_ by Horn and Johnson, some works on [multi-agent consensus for control systems](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-84800-015-5), as well as typical online sources ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gershgorin_circle_theorem), [Wolfram Mathworld](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/GershgorinCircleTheorem.html)). I realize this isn't a very satisfying list, and I'm happy to edit my original wording. However I believe the question is still valid.

Comment: From a quick scan of Google Scholar, [these](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0024379587903351?ref=cra_js_challenge&fr=RR-1) [papers](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0024379598102197) give a few results in this direction. I'm curious if there's additional literature on the topic.

Comment: It may be helpful to play around with examples on nice spaces like $\ell^1$ or $\ell^2$ where the bounded operators are not hard to construct and can be given in component form. Even defining what a generalization of the theorem should be on general Banach spaces is likely technical.